# backbone.js set callback on before save?

Tags: backbone.js, callback

I was asked to remove couple of attributes from a backbone model (which was optional) where they exists. My first intent was to place something like a `before_save` callback on a model. But i didn't find any information googling.
is it possible to do that on a backbone side?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just override default `Model.save` and add your callback to it.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

   save: function (key, val, options) {
     this.beforeSave(key, val, options);
     return Backbone.Model.prototype.save.call(this, key, val, options);
   },

   beforeSave: function (key, val, options) {

   }

})
```

If you want only to remove particular attributes from being sent to the server than you may override `Model.toJSON` method.

Comment: Nice answer, I like the approach.